# How to scrape JSON web pages

Tags: python, json, scrapy

Hey so I have some experience scraping html but never json and so I need to scrape the following web page using scrapy, http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/search?search-type=category&id=5061, and I found a tutorial online that uses scrapy along with jmspath to scrape json data from the web.  And I got the tutorial to work but I am trying to alter it to work with my website to no luck.  No errors but it does not return any data.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

items.py

```
import scrapy


class NameItem(scrapy.Item):
    """User item definition for jsonplaceholder /LoginSpider endpoint."""
    name = scrapy.Field()
    condition = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    rarity = scrapy.Field()
```

LoginSpider.py

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from ..items import NameItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join, MapCompose, SelectJmes


class UserSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """Spider to scrape `http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/search?search-type=category&id=5061`."""
    name = 'LoginSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/search?search-type=category&id=5061']
    start_urls = ['http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/search?search-type=category&id=5061']
    # dictionary to map UserItem fields to Jmes query paths
    jmes_paths = {
            'name': 'name',
            'condition': 'condition',
            'price': 'price',
            'rarity': 'rarity',
            }

    def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        for user in jsonresponse:
            loader = ItemLoader(item=NameItem())  # create an ItemLoader to populate a NameItem
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(str)  # apply str conversion on each value
            loader.default_output_processor = Join(' ')
            for (field, path) in self.jmes_paths.items():
                loader.add_value(field, SelectJmes(path)(user))
            yield loader.load_item()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response of this url http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/search?search-type=category&id=5061has 3 levels:

1. 'Ok'
2. 'search'
3. 'results'  ## this contain the data

And **results** key has multiple values what you should iterate.
Inside the values are the data.
Try this code, I hope you can help.

This is the module items.py

```
class SoResponseItem(scrapy.Item):
        name = scrapy.Field()
        condition = scrapy.Field()
        price = scrapy.Field()
        rarity = scrapy.Field()
```

This is the spider

```
import scrapy
import json
from SO_response.items import SoResponseItem

class LoginspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'LoginSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.starcitygames.com']
    url = 'http://www.starcitygames.com/'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.urljoin('buylist/search?search-type=category&id=5061')
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_data)

    def parse_data(self, response):
        jsonreponse = json.loads(response.body)
        for result in jsonreponse['results']:
            for index in range(len(result)):
                items = SoResponseItem()
                items['name'] = result[index]['name']
                items['condition'] = result[index]['condition']
                items['price'] = result[index]['price']
                items['rarity'] = result[index]['rarity']
                yield items
```

Try in your shell:
scrapy crawl  -o jmes.json